# How to count number of found elements in docx with python?

Tags: python, regex, counting, python-docx

I've found some sentences with regex in .docx file and printed matches with this code:

```
import re

from docx import Document

document = Document('Алтайский край.docx')

reg542 = re.compile(r"(?i)Доля записей на прием к врачу, совершенных гражданами дистанционно.*"
                    r"|(?i)Доля граждан, у которых сформированы интегрированные электронные медицинские карты.*"
                    r"|(?i)Доля граждан, находящихся на диспансерном наблюдении.*"
                    r"|(?i)Доля медицинских организаций.*"
                    r"|(?i)Доля врачебных консилиумов.*"
                    r"|(?i)Доля консультаций.*"
                    r"|(?i)Доля граждан..которым доступны врачебные.*"
                    r"|(?i)Доля приобретаемых за бюджетные.*")

for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                if reg542.search(paragraph.text):
                    print(paragraph.text)
```

And now I want to count how many matches were found, but i don't know how, because `len()` and `.count` are not working.

Comment: How about incrementing a counter variable in place of `print`?

Comment: How does it look in code? :)

Comment: `m = 0` … `m += 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me

```
for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                if reg542.search(paragraph.text):
                    print(paragraph.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `re.findall()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Also consider `re.finditer()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer which gives you a match object for each match, containing the start index of each match, etc.

Either one will allow you to count the number of matches in a particular paragraph.

```
counter = 0
for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
    matches = reg542.findall(paragraph.text)
    counter += len(matches)
    if matches:
        print(paragraph.text)
```

Comment: `counter += len(matches)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

It says :(

Comment: @Pavel apologies, reg542.search needed to be changed to `reg542.findall`. Fixed in answer.